# Is it safe to use CRTP for destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, crtp

CRTP can call child class method like virtual function although virtual function is resolved while runtime.

As far as I know, it is not safe to call virtual function in a destructor.
Is same thing true for CRTP?
Is it safe or unsafe to call child method using CRTP?

Edit:

If it is not unsafe, what about multiple inheritance case?
For instance,

```
template<typename T, typename V>
struct CRTP {
    ~CRTP()
    {
        static_cast<V*>(static_cast<T*>(this))->run();
    }
};

struct Run {
    void run() { std::cout << "run" << std::endl; }
};

struct A : Run, CRTP<A, Run> {

};
```

Here, the order of destruction is A->CRTP->Run.
Is it safe to call functions of Run in destructor of CRTP?

Comment: virtual methods called in constructor/destructor doesn't use virtual dispatch.

Comment: In body of base destructor, you no longer have access to derived data.

Comment: Is that the last iteration of the question? I'd rather not invest time into answering if you are going to shift the goal post again.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm sorry to add new question. If another additional question strike me, I'll post as new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As far as I know, it is not safe to call virtual function in a destructor. Is same thing true for CRTP? Is it safe or unsafe to call child method using CRTP?

It is not safe. The very same considerations apply. In the constructor or the destructor, there is **no derived object** yet/anymore. So calling its member function, be it by CRTP or by cheating with virtual functions and indirection via non-virtual members, leads to undefined behavior.

Your second example still has undefined behavior, unfortunately. You [may not `static_cast<>(this)`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#6.4) to anything other than to cv-qualified `void` or `void*`, [or to a base](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.cdtor#2) (which `Run` is not).

Comment: If it's about object destruction, what about multiple inheritance case which CRTP calls another base class method? I edited the question.